# How to allow only single page be displayed vie iframe?

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, content-security-policy

I have a page in my Laravel project which I need to make available for use throughout iframe. Not the whole app but only one single page available for iframing inside only one trusted domain.

I learned that Laravel has a middleware, which protects the whole app from being displayed via iframe, called `FrameGuard`

```
class FrameGuard
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

But this is the framework's middleware, not project files, so can't change it. Even if I had decided to change it I would have to change handle method to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        //$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM' https://example.com);  obsolate

        $response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy' frame-ancestors 'self' https://www.example.com);

        return $response;
    }
```

Since it has now a different header would it be the cause of any problems in the future?
Also, if allowing only a single page to be used in iframe programmatically possible do I have to change other configurations like e.g. Nginx settings?

It feels like a lack of information on this topic on the internet. Any thoughts and contributions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking into creating your own middleware for this? Have a look at https://voutzinos.com/blog/cross-origin-iframe-laravel/ - seems like this is pretty close to what you're after.